# memory allocation vs array size definition

Tags: c

In C, for example anytime I wanna deal with strings (which C does not support), I can do either

```
 char* String = (char*) malloc(25);
```

Or

```
 char String[25];
```

I'd like to know what the main difference between these two ways of defining the length of an array is in C (other than that, the first is a pointer the second is not).

I'd also like to know which one is safer.

Comment: Dynamic allocation (with malloc) allocates memory on the heap. Static definition, the second example, uses the stack. Neither are particularly safer, but is you overflow on the stack, you'll probably affect other statically defined variables.

Comment: Strictly speaking, C knows nothing about stacks or heaps.

Comment: C does know about *automatic storage* and *dynamic storage* however, and it's safe to assume that when someone talks about *stack* or *heap* they mean those two things respectively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `char* String = (char*) malloc(25);`
2. `char String[25];`

The main difference between the two array objects is the lifetime. The first one the lifetime of the object starts at `malloc` return and ends when `free` is called. The second has a lifetime which depends on the scope where it is declared. At block scope, the object is created when the block is entered until the `}`. At file scope, the lifetime starts with the program and ends when the program ends.

The other difference is `String` in the first case is a pointer and in the second case is an array name. For example, `sizeof String` in the first case yields the size of the pointer object but yields the size of the array object in the second case.

As a final note, [do not cast](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Can you explain a little more specially how they differ in life time please.